# pygame import error with imageext

Tags: python, pygame

I made a program which opens the webcam using pygame. I was trying to capture the image and save it to my current directory by using pygame.save(img, 'image.jpg').

```
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image
import sys

pygame.camera.init()

cameras = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

print "Using camera %s ..." % cameras[0]

webcam = pygame.camera.Camera(cameras[0])

webcam.start()

# grab first frame
img = webcam.get_image()

WIDTH = img.get_width()
HEIGHT = img.get_height()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WIDTH, HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("pyGame Camera View")

while True :
    for e in pygame.event.get() :
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT :
            pygame.image.save(img, 'image.jpg')
        sys.exit()



    # draw frame
    screen.blit(img, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    # grab next frame    
    img = webcam.get_image()
```

But this program is giving an error :

```
Using camera /dev/video0 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cam1.py", line 27, in <module>
    pygame.image.save(img, 'image.jpg')
ImportError: No module named imageext
```

What is the problem with the code ? please help me ! is there any other way to save the image ?

Comment: It does not necessarily look like there's anything wrong with your code, but perhaps it's a faulty PyGame installation.

Comment: when I changed the extension to .bmp the code worked ! pygame by default supports only uncompressed BMP images

Comment: Yes if you haven't installed PyGame with full image support, as described in their documentation: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html. Most PyGame installations should however have full image support, so I still believe there's something wrong with your installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I changed the extension to .bmp the code worked ! pygame by default supports only uncompressed BMP images

I don't have PyGame with full image support, that's why I am forced to stick with BMP format of images

more info is given [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) (Pygame official documentation)